# Sagepay returning 3070 : The RelatedVPSTxId is required

Tags: php, opayo

I'm trying to make a continuous authority payment using Sagepay server integration but I keep getting the following error returned:

```
3070 : The RelatedVPSTxId is required.
```

I have made a previous payment which all goes through fine and so I have the VPSTxId, SecurityKey, TxAuthNo etc stored which I am passing as the parameters of this REPEAT transaction so I can't understand why it's not working. These are the parameters I'm passing:

```
VPSProtocol=3.0&TxType=REPEAT&Currency=GBP&Vendor=********&RedirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2F&NotificationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.mycarneedsa.com%2Fsagepay_notification&ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2F&Description=MyCarNeedsA.com+membership+fee&AllowGiftAid=0&ApplyAVSCV2=0&Apply3DSecure=0&Profile=NORMAL&AccountType=E&Amount=14.00&BillingFirstnames=Joe&BillingSurname=Bloggs&BillingAddress1=1+Bridge+Street&BillingAddress2=&BillingCity=Chester&BillingPostCode=CH11NW&BillingCountry=GB&BillingState=&BillingPhone=01244123456&RelatedVPSTxId=%7B2857B5EC-3DF7-731C-9CE2-CBF3540E1EEB%7D&RelatedSecurityKey=ZIEHJFKFKJ&RelatedTxAuthNo=7895147&payment_id=50&VendorTxCode=MCNA140926122642-19738491&DeliveryFirstnames=Joe&DeliverySurname=Bloggs&DeliveryAddress1=1+Bridge+Street&DeliveryAddress2=&DeliveryCity=Chester&DeliveryPostCode=CH11NW&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryState=&DeliveryPhone=01244123456&CustomerEMail=geoff%40google.com&VPSTxId=%7B2857B5EC-3DF7-731C-9CE2-CBF3540E1EEB%7D&SecurityKey=ZIEHJFKFKJ&TxAuthNo=7895147&AVSCV2=SECURITY+CODE+MATCH+ONLY&AddressResult=NOTMATCHED&PostCodeResult=NOTMATCHED&CV2Result=MATCHED&GiftAid=0&ThreeDSecureStatus=NOTCHECKED&Status=AUTHORISED&CardType=VISA&Last4Digits=0006&created=2014-09-26+11%3A51%3A21&updated=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00&CustomerEmail=geoff%40google.com
```

I've obscured the vendor name with stars in this example but it is set correctly in my actual post

Comment: Are you passing a blank value in the `RelatedVPSTxId`  field?

Comment: Nope it's definitely set

Comment: Capture what you send to SagePay, and provide it in your post, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH I've sorted it! I was posting through some unnecessary variables it seems and removing them made it work!